# Security Exception App.Utils.getDeviceSerial Error. How to fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I will make the file sharing android app like share it and xender.

but my app users face some problems in my app. and in google play console error section it shows Security Exception App.Utils.getDeviceSerial Error.

I am try to find the error but I can not able to find the error.

please help to find the issue in my coding.

This is my manifest file

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.genonbeta.TrebleShot">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="@string/app_name"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_trebleshot_original_white_128dp"
        android:label="@string/text_appName"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.WebView"
            android:screenOrientation="locked"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_appName"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="locked"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.ShareActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_appName"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="genonbeta.intent.action.TREBLESHOT_SEND_TEXT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <action android:name="genonbeta.intent.action.TREBLESHOT_SEND" />
                <action android:name="genonbeta.intent.action.TREBLESHOT_SEND_MULTIPLE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!--
                <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service"
                android:value=".service.DeviceChooserService" />
            -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.AddDevicesToTransferActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_addDevicesToTransfer"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.FileExplorerActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_fileExplorer"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.TextStreamActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_textStream"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.ConnectionManagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_connectDevices"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.ContentSharingActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_send"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.FilePickerActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_fileExplorer" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.ViewTransferActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_transactionViewer"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <!-- expected file name pattern .5435-4543-4354-ewrw.tshare -->
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.tshare" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.tshare" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.ManageDevicesActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_manageDevices" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/butn_search" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.PreferencesActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_preferences" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.TextEditorActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_textEditor" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.ChangeStoragePathActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.genonbeta.intent.action.UPDATE_STORAGE_PATH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.ThirdPartyLibrariesActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_thirdPartyLibraries" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.ChangelogActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_changelog" /> <!-- todo: Remember, we are always using dark theme for this for better effects -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.BarcodeScannerActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_scanQrCode"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.BarcodeScannerActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_welcome"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.activity.WebShareActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_webShare"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrebleShot.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.receiver.NetworkStatusReceiver"
            android:process=":transfer">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.receiver.DialogEventReceiver"
            android:process=":transfer" />

        <service
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.service.CommunicationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/text_communicationService"
            android:process=":transfer" />
        <service
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.service.DeviceChooserService"
            android:label="@string/text_chooserTargetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.chooser.ChooserTargetService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.service.DeviceScannerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="genonbeta.intent.action.SCAN_DEVICES" />
                <action android:name="genonbeta.intent.action.ADD_IP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.service.WorkerService"
            android:label="@string/text_workerService" />
        <service
            android:name="com.IApps.IndianShareIt.service.CommunicationToggleTile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_trebleshot_white_24dp_static"
            android:label="@string/text_shareFiles"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE"
            android:process=":transfer">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

<!--        sample - ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713-->
<!--        main - ca-app-pub-2802607728843215~8939176355-->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my welcome activity with permissions

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity
{
    public final static String TAG = WelcomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ViewGroup mSplashView;
    private ViewGroup mProfileView;
    private ViewGroup mPermissionsView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        setSkipPermissionRequest(true);
        setWelcomePageDisallowed(true);

        final FloatingActionButton nextButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_welcome_view_next);
        final AppCompatImageView previousButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_welcome_view_previous);
        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.activity_welcome_progress_bar);
        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.activity_welcome_view_pager);
        final DynamicViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new DynamicViewPagerAdapter();

        {
            @ColorInt
            int appliedColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, AppUtils.getReference(this, R.attr.colorSecondary));

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(progressBar.getProgressDrawable());

                DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, appliedColor);
                progressBar.setProgressDrawable(DrawableCompat.unwrap(wrapDrawable));
            } else
                progressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(appliedColor));
        }

        {
            mSplashView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_welcome_page_1, null, false);
            pagerAdapter.addView(mSplashView);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            mPermissionsView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_welcome_page_3, null, false);
            pagerAdapter.addView(mPermissionsView);
            checkPermissionsState();

            mPermissionsView.findViewById(R.id.layout_welcome_page_3_request_button)
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            requestRequiredPermissions(false);
                        }
                    });
        }

        {
            mProfileView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_welcome_page_2, null, false);
            pagerAdapter.addView(mProfileView);
            setUserProfile();
        }

        pagerAdapter.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_welcome_page_4, null, false));

        {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_welcome_page_5, null, false);
            AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f, 1.0f);

            alphaAnimation.setDuration(2000);
            alphaAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            alphaAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

            view.findViewById(R.id.layout_welcome_page_5_text)
                    .setAnimation(alphaAnimation);

            pagerAdapter.addView(view);
        }
        progressBar.setMax((pagerAdapter.getCount() - 1) * 100);

        previousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1 >= 0)
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1, true);
            }
        });

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1 < pagerAdapter.getCount())
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                else {
                    // end presentation
                    getDefaultPreferences().edit()
                            .putBoolean("introduction_shown", true)
                            .apply();

                    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
            {
                progressBar.setProgress((position * 100) + (int) (positionOffset * 100));

                if (position == 0) {
                    progressBar.setAlpha(positionOffset);
                    previousButton.setAlpha(positionOffset);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setAlpha(1.0f);
                    previousButton.setAlpha(1.0f);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {
                OvershootInterpolator interpolator = new OvershootInterpolator();

                nextButton.setImageResource(position + 1 >= pagerAdapter.getCount()
                        ? R.drawable.ic_check_white_24dp
                        : R.drawable.ic_navigate_next_white_24dp);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
            {
            }
        });

        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        slideSplashView();
        setUserProfile();
        checkPermissionsState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserProfileUpdated()
    {
        super.onUserProfileUpdated();
        setUserProfile();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        checkPermissionsState();
    }

    protected void checkPermissionsState()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23)
            return;

        boolean permissionsOk = AppUtils.checkRunningConditions(this);

        mPermissionsView.findViewById(R.id.layout_welcome_page_3_perm_ok_image)
                .setVisibility(permissionsOk ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        mPermissionsView.findViewById(R.id.layout_welcome_page_3_request_button)
                .setVisibility(permissionsOk ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected void setUserProfile()
    {
        if (mProfileView != null) {
            NetworkDevice localDevice = AppUtils.getLocalDevice(getApplicationContext());

            ImageView imageView = mProfileView.findViewById(R.id.layout_profile_picture_image_default);
            ImageView editImageView = mProfileView.findViewById(R.id.layout_profile_picture_image_preferred);
            TextView deviceNameText = mProfileView.findViewById(R.id.header_default_device_name_text);
            TextView versionText = mProfileView.findViewById(R.id.header_default_device_version_text);

            deviceNameText.setText(localDevice.nickname);
            versionText.setText(localDevice.versionName);
            loadProfilePictureInto(localDevice.nickname, imageView);

            editImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    startProfileEditor();
                }
            });

            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mProfileView);
        }
    }

    protected void slideSplashView()
    {
        mSplashView.findViewById(R.id.layout_welcome_page_1_splash_image)
                .setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.enter_from_bottom_centered));

        mSplashView.findViewById(R.id.layout_welcome_page_1_details)
                .setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.enter_from_bottom));
    }

    
}
```